# I can't display div on top of another (IE11 issue)

Tags: css, flexbox, css-float, internet-explorer-11, css-grid

Need help regarding floating a div over another. I'm having issue with IE11 as it pushes other div's at the bottom and not floating sideways. Basically this whole issue was div's not floating correctly , I just thought that someone might have experienced this already.

Attaching the snippet of my code . Please hover on **click me**

```css
#row1:hover { 
 top:0px; 
 z-index:1;
 width:450px;
 position:relative; 
 height:200px;
}
#row2 .row-skin { 
 position:relative; 
 top:2px; 
}

#row3 .row-skin { 
 position:relative; 
 top:1px; 
}
#row4 .row-skin { 
    position:relative; 
 top:1px; 
}

.row-skin{
 color: #FFF;
 background-color: #FF00D8;
 display: inline-block;
 border-radius: 25px;
 background: #003466;
 padding: 16px;
 width: 250px;
 height: 145px;
 margin: .50em 0; /* for separating portal-tiles vertically*/
  overflow: hidden;
 overflow-x: hidden; 
  transition: height .5s, width .5s;
 transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
 z-index:0; 
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) {
 .flex-grid{
  -moz-column-count: 4;
  -webkit-column-count: 4;
  column-count: 4;
 }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
 .flex-grid {
  -moz-column-count: 4;
  -webkit-column-count: 4;
  column-count: 4;
 }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 960px) {
 .flex-grid {
  -moz-column-count: 4;
  -webkit-column-count: 4;
  column-count: 4;
 }
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-grid">
  <div id= "row1" class="row-skin" >Click me </div>
  <div id= "row2" class="row-skin" >Sample 2</div>
  <div id= "row3" class="row-skin" >Sample3</div>
  <div id= "row4" class="row-skin">Sample4</div>
  <div id= "row5" class="row-skin" >Sample5</div>
  <div id= "row6" class="row-skin" >Sample 6</div>
  <div id= "row7" class="row-skin" >Sample 7</div>
  <div id= "row8" class="row-skin">Sample 8</div>  
</div>
```

When you run the code hove to **click me**, you'll see that the row below is being pushed downwards and also it doesn't float correctly on either sides.

Comment: I'm getting the exact same behavior in Chrome and IE11. https://jsfiddle.net/Lro3rr5z/1/

Comment: Firefox Dev.Ed.55+ on W10 the same result

Comment: What is it you want to happen? Right now there is just not enough room for the 1st box to grow that amount of pixels (`z-index: 1` or not).

Comment: Hi! What I'd like is make not anything but the selective div to be moving . I can't achieve using that approach.

Answer (score 0):

Change `position: relative` to `position: absolute` in your `#row1:hover`. I try this solution in IE11 - looks like it fix your trouble :)

Comment: I tried that before wont work, as it will move the other row to the space that was selected (float). Thanks anyways for looking at it

Comment: Add wrapper for your `.row` with `position:relative`. It must help you.